# "I'm warned to be contrary" Could somebody explain what does this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, songs

I was trying to translate/understand the song "God help the girl" and faced out with following

```
...
You have been warned, I'm warned to be contrary
Backward at school, I wrote from right to left
Teacher never cared for me
Preacher said a prayer for me
God help the girl, she needs all the help she can get
...
```

And I've already searched meanings of word 'contrary', but still have some problems with understanding. What does she mean when she is singing "I'm warned to be contrary"?

Probably it's something that mean she consists from different persons and they are opposed to each other? (sorry for bad english ^^ )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/bellesebastian/godhelpthegirl.html  has a different transcription and makes more sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on an erroneous transcription of song lyrics.

Comment: wow! tnx. really it's wrong transcription. Really I used the source with mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Just before I start the answer proper, I'll quote the line:

> You have been warned
>   I'm **born** to be contrary

The protagonist has, from birth, ploughed a furrow that goes against the grain of the behaviour of the people around her.

Chambers Dictionary gives us a definition of:

> *contrary* adj
>   1) (often contrary to something) opposite; quite different; opposed.
>   3) obstinate, perverse, self-willed or wayward.

and tells us it is derived from the latin *contrarius*, from *contra* meaning opposite.

Later on, she shows just how obstinately, perversely opposed she is to doing what most people would do:

> My love for him is absurd
>   If he gave me a sign I'd think about it for a week
>   I'd build it up and then I'd turn him down

She tells us how much she loves him, and how she'd turn him down if he showed interest in her.